# Creating swagger example models asp.net core web api

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I do not know how to add the example models with the latest swagger (swashbuckle.aspnetcore4.0.1) NuGet package.

earlier I used to do with this, but i donot get argument with the latest interface

```
 public class SwaggerExamplesSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
 {

    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {}
 }
```

I need the latest usage to create the example model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here for the latest package

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enrich-schema-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed an update to Swashbuckle, the sort of official unofficial way to add examples is via the [`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4ipaawNfhAhULd6wKHcfGBEgQFjADegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nuget.org%2Fpackages%2FSwashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples%2F&usg=AOvVaw0h3yCFp8LYjba1CkAHfGFp) NuGet package. I'm sure you could roll your own, if you really wanted to, but you'd likely just create something like this anyways. In other words, there's nothing I'm aware directly built-in to add examples.

Comment: the repository you mentioned is uninformative for the latest package usage